# java function matching rules different from C++

Tags: java, c++, function, signature

```
package java;

public class Question {

    interface A {}

    class B0 implements A {}

    static void f(B0 b) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a = new B0();
        B0 b = new B0();

        Question.f(a); // compiler error
        Question.f(b);

    }

}
```

This is the compiler error:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method f(Question.B0) in the type Question is not applicable for the arguments (Question.A) Question.java   /java/src/java  line 18 Java Problem

In C++ this would work, the runtime-type of a is B0, so Question.f is a match.

Why does Java make this an error?

Comment: This wouldn't compile in C++ either. `a` is not a `B0`. `a` is an `A`.

Comment: And even if it compiles in C++, what makes you think Java is equal?

Comment: Even with pointers it won't work because `f(a)` must perform a downcast, so you need to `static_cast` (can also use the safer `dynamic_cast` if you have virtual functions).

Comment: Even if it did compile in c++, Java is a completely different language, with different compile-time and run-time rules. It's not a great idea to try to take c++ and hope it compiles in Java. By "why," do you mean "why are they different" or "why does Java work this way [regardless of how other languages do it]?"

Comment: Please provide C++ sample that you believe is equivalent and compiles. So far looks like you have false assumption and hence anything can be derived from it.

Comment: `In C++ this would work`  but what's the point of saying that?  You are writing Java code, not C++ code.

Comment: The fun part is it *doesn't* work in C++. A  cannot be guaranteed to satisfy the contract established by B0.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as this isn't the C++/Java issue that the author thought it was according to the last comment below the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because B0 is a specialization of A, A may have less functionality than B0.

f requires  B0. f could reasonably expect to access a method or member that is not present in A. If this compiles in C++, the compiler is broken.

The equivalent in C++ is

```
class A
{

};

class B0: public A
{

};

static void f(B0 * b)
{

}

int main() {

    A * a = new B0();
    B0 * b = new B0();

    f(a); // compiler error
    f(b);

    delete a;
    delete b;
}
```

Which doesn't work in several flavours of GCC 4 or MSVS 10.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work in Java or C++. There was some situation where I thought Java was behaving differently from C++, but, this was not it.